# Ping Command Says "Ping: NaN"

Tags: javascript

For my ping command, there are no errors in the terminal, but when I send the command in discord, my bot just sends "Ping: NaN". How can I fix this? Here is my code in ping.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client();
    
module.exports = {
        name: 'ping',
        description: "pings",
        execute(message, args) {
            message.react("");
            message.channel.send(`Ping: ${client.ws.ping}`);
        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem you need to put your `message.channel.send(...);` into `client.on(...)`:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  message.react('');
  message.channel.send(`Ping: ${client.ws.ping}`);
});
```